# Windows 7 / PuTTY drop IPv6 TCP connections on brief outages

Tags: windows-7, networking, putty, ipv6, tcp

This is an IPv6-version of the following question:

[Why Windows 7 / PuTTY drop TCP connections even on very brief outages?](https://superuser.com/questions/529511/why-windows-7-putty-drop-tcp-connections-even-on-very-brief-outages)

After moving from IPv4 to IPv6, I've noticed that my IPv6 connections would drop all the time (e.g. overnight).  I've now finally caught it dropping after only a couple of seconds when IPv6 connectivity was temporarily lost on the remote host.

It would appear that creating `TcpMaxDataRetransmissions`, with a value like `0x18` (`24`), within `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\TCPIP6\Parameters`, has no effect in Windows 7 (unlike the corresponding IPv4 setting).  Why?

**How do I prevent the IPv6 TCP connections from dropping so quickly?**  My IPv4 connections remains active for minutes during the temporary periods of no connectivity, after creating the same value (and a reboot) within `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters`, as per the referenced question.

Comment: Do you have native IPv6 or a tunnel? From whom?

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Native IPv6 on the client end, with static IPv6 provisioning (IPv6 address, preflen and gateway are manually specified in the IPv6 Properties), with IPv4 done through DHCP.